# what is the relationship between horizontal frequency and CPU power?

Tags: cpu, video, performance

I'm building a device that will read video input, encode it and save it to disk. I read about horizontal frequency as a measure for video capacity, in khz. is that the same hz as in CPU power? what is the relationship?

Comment: Because of differences in microarchitecture, the Hz for CPU power isn't even the same as the Hz for CPU power sometimes. Please give the context of where you saw the statement "horizontal frequency" as there may be a precise definition elsewhere in the same datasheet, so that we can avoid guesswork.

Comment: here: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-can-i-read-vga-signals-w-an-arduino/105038/9; thanks

Comment: there is no relationship between the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal scan frequency and vertical frequency are multiplied per frame by the number of pixels to determine the Pixel Rate which is the highest frequency but much lower than a CPU.

This refers to the analog pixel rate and not the digital HDMI pixel rate which approaches that of a CPU. Yet HDMI bit rate is not handled by the CPU directly and uses standard GPU hardware and clocks.

None of these terms are really an indication of CPU power, just flexibility of the Video chips, as Horizontal frequency is just the rate of scanning each row of pixels.

However if you attempted to scan VGA signals with an embedded device it would be slower than a Commadore computer (lol).

Look up VGA to USB capture cards to understand what is needed.